# After updating the kernel I can't log into the desktop. Only see the wallpaper

Tags: unity, nvidia, kernel, compiz, 14.10

Im using Ubuntu 14.10. I have been using Nvidia propitiatory drivers downloaded from Nvidia. Everything worked fine. In the morning I got an update to the kernel and I applied it. After restarting, lightdm came up as usual. I applied the password and then no Unity. Only the wallpaper.

I reinstalled the nvidia drivers, removed it, installed from the repo (nvidia-current), removed, installed nouveau driver... Reset unity, compiz, set permissions for home, remove Xauthority. Nothing helped! How can I fix my system now? Please help!

**Update** The guest session works!

Comment: login to the tty and install gnome. Many have faced this problem with Unity. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`.

Comment: Did you try:
`sudo rm -r ~/.*`

Comment: @Naveen Thanks bro I fixed it! I tried to reset unity from a text terminal (ctrl+alt+f1). It didn't work. Threw a dbus error. Couldn't open a terminal even with the shortcut after login.

But later found that the guest account is working! So, I created a new admin user, logged in successfully and then reset unity. It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it! I tried to reset unity from a text terminal (ctrl+alt+f1). It didn't work. Threw a dbus error. Couldn't open a terminal even with the shortcut after login.

But later found that the guest account is working! So, I created a new admin user, logged in successfully and then reset unity. It worked!